# Get previous authenticated user before warden.authenticat! got called when create new session with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, warden

Using:

- Rails 7.1 (with API mode)
- devise 4.9.3
- postman for the following tests

---

First, I logged in with `user A` with email and password. I got what were expected.

But next, I try to login with `user B` with its email and password, and I got

- 201 status
- user A's info (wrong one, it should be B's)
- user A's session_id in cookies (wrong one, it should be B's)

When I insert a break point before `warden.authenticate!(auth_options)` in sessions#create and send the request with B's login info, I can already get the previous authenticated user A by `warden.user`.

Even postman will bring A's session_id with B's login info to the server, I should not get A's info. Can anyone please point me out any setting or point I need to pay attention to? Thanks

---

settings:

config/application.rb

```
module Api
  class Application < Rails::Application
    config.load_defaults 7.1
    config.autoload_lib(ignore: %w(assets tasks))
    config.api_only = true
    config.session_store :active_record_store, key: '_session_id'
    config.middleware.use Rack::MethodOverride
    config.middleware.use ActionDispatch::Cookies
    config.middleware.use config.session_store, config.session_options
  end
end
```

initializers/devise.rb

```
Devise.setup do |config|
  config.mailer_sender = 'example@example.com'
  require 'devise/orm/active_record'
  config.case_insensitive_keys = [:email]
  config.strip_whitespace_keys = [:email]
  config.skip_session_storage = [:http_auth]
  config.stretches = Rails.env.test? ? 1 : 12
  config.reconfirmable = true
  config.expire_all_remember_me_on_sign_out = true
  config.password_length = 6..128
  config.email_regexp = /\A[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\z/
  config.reset_password_within = 6.hours
  config.navigational_formats = []
  config.sign_out_via = :delete
  config.responder.error_status = :unprocessable_entity
  config.responder.redirect_status = :see_other
end
```